# Christmas trees - real or fake? When did the U.S. Christmas tree consumer begin preferring artificial trees to real trees?

Tags: united-states, social-history, christmas, consumer-goods

[image]
<sup>Source: National Christmas Tree Association via [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/209249/purchase-figures-for-real-and-fake-christmas-trees-in-the-us/).</sup>

### Background

Our family was watching (again) [A Christmas Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Story) last night, and during the scene where the Old Man is bargaining to purchase a Christmas tree, he starts haggling with the salesman:

> You know the neighbors bought one of those brand new *plastic* trees... the thing looks like it was made of...green pipe cleaners!

Obviously in the 1940's, artificial trees were still rather new (and not very realistic). But over the decades since then they have improved. In fact, from the data I have been able to find thus far, since at least 2013 (perhaps even further back than that), anywhere from 75% to 80% of Americans who display Christmas trees in their homes use artificial instead of real trees. This may seem counter-intuitive when looking at the annual purchase breakdowns in the info graphic above, but the key is that artificial trees are kept and used from year to year anywhere for four to eight (or more) years, whereas real trees last only one holiday season and must be purchased fresh again the following year.

I have been looking for annual tree preference trends, and I'm sure I'm close with the sources I have searched included below - but so far I have been unable to find trend data that would reveal what I am looking for in the question, namely:

## Question

At what point in American history did annual artificial Christmas tree *usage* (not purchases) exceed 50%, thus eclipsing the use of real trees in American homes during the holiday season?

## Sources:

- Treetopia - [Christmas Tree Statistics](https://www.treetopia.com/christmas-tree-statistics-a/302.htm)
- The Times News - [By the numbers: Real vs fake Christmas trees](https://www.thetimesnews.com/news/20161125/by-numbers-real-vs-fake-christmas-trees);
- [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/209249/purchase-figures-for-real-and-fake-christmas-trees-in-the-us/);
- American Christmas Tree Association - [Most American households will celebrate Christmas with a Christmas tree](https://www.christmastreeassociation.org/most-americans-christmas-tree/);
- On the House - [Choosing a real Christmas, or artificial, tree and the History of the festive tree](https://www.onthehouse.com/choosing-a-real-christmas-or-artificial-tree-and-the-history-of-the-festive-tree/);
- Bradenton Herald - [Christmas tree farmers combat popularity of artificial trees](https://www.bradenton.com/news/business/article222939560.html);
- How Stuff Works - [Christmas Tree Trends](https://people.howstuffworks.com/culture-traditions/holidays-christmas/christmas-tree7.htm);
- Wikipedia - [Christmas tree - Artificial trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree#Artificial_trees);
- Wikipedia - [Christmas tree production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_production).

Comment: I don't know how common this is but what about people who re-use a real tree simply by having it in a (large) pot? When it gets too big to cart around (after maybe 2 to 4 years), you transfer it to a permanent location outside and start again with a smaller one. This is great for the environment and great for people who think plastic trees aren't the real deal (like me).

Comment: @LarsBosteen that's actually a great idea and it reminds me somewhat of the evergreen forest that now surrounds my old family homestead where I grew up (years ago and hundreds of miles away)... my family would get a live tree for Christmas and keep it potted in the house (decorated, of course), and then when the season was over, plant it on the estate (several acres). I could probably point out a few of them today and tell you what year they were used. Unfortunately a few of them didn't survive more than a year but most of them are much taller than the two story house now.

Comment: One of the great benefits of an artificial tree is that you can keep the lighting attached. "Putting up the tree" is a matter of getting the (rather light) box from the basement, stand up the tree, plug in the lights, and hang the decorations for this year. No carting around, no looking for a new one every couple of years (and you'll have to *find* a potted tree, or a tree you'd be allowed to dig up -- those aren't common where I live). And if you're living in an appartment complex or similar, you won't have anywhere to put a potted tree, so... we went fake eight years ago. ;-)

Comment: We've been using a fiber optic tree, about 2 feet tall, since the mid-1980s.  It has the colors built into the base!

Comment: @DevSolar yep - we went artificial some 20 or 25 years ago. I think we are on our 4th one in all that time.

Comment: @KerryL: I had to convince my wife. She was sentimental about having a "real" tree. It took our kids siding with me on "I don't want to look at a dying tree every year" and a nice fake tree on display in the shop to have her come around. ;-)

Comment: While I have no idea of the numbers (or even how to obtain them), there are people who do not purchase their holiday trees.  They cut their own.

Comment: @jamesqf good point, though that number has no doubt significantly declined over the decades as the US has evolved from an agrarian / rural society to an industrial / urban / suburban one. I would _expect_ these to be included today with those who have real trees in general, purchased or not :-)

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Not a complete answer, but another data point: based on Gallup polls, in 1989 52% used real and 40% fake, while in 2004 the figures were real 37% fake 58% (remainder either have multiple trees or say "it depends"). https://abcnews.go.com/images/Politics/971a4ChristmasTrees.pdf

Comment: To the extent that “consumer” implies individuals and families I would posit that the graph is not limited to consumers but includes businesses as well. Further, I would imagine that business are MUCH more likely to choose and artificial tree than an individual is.

Comment: @StuartF Good find, and maybe as close to an answer as we'll get.

Comment: @StuartF if you care to expand your comment into an Answer it would get my +1 and most likely Accepted if nothing closer turns up!